# .NET - c# - Cross partition query is required but disabled trouble on DocumentDB data access

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cosmosdb

I have written the following code to fetch a record from the DocumentDB

```
private static void QueryDocuments1(DocumentClient client)
{

    IQueryable<SearchInput> queryable =
client.CreateDocumentQuery<SearchInput>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DocumentDBName, DocumentDBCollectionName))
        .Where(x => x.Receiver == "8907180");
    List<SearchInput> posts = queryable.ToList();
}
```

And it is showing the following error on the code line `List<SearchInput> posts = queryable.ToList();`

> {"Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set
>   x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify
>   x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this
>   exception.\r\nActivityId: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx"}

Please help me on it...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should use  `CreateDocumentQuery` method with `FeedOptions` object as a parameter, this class has a property for `x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition` called `EnableCrossPartitionQuery`.

Please follow links https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn850285.aspx 
For REST https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api

### Example:

you should have

```
 var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
 IQueryable<SearchInput> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<SearchInput>
 (UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DocumentDBName, 
 DocumentDBCollectionName), option ) .Where(x => x.Receiver == "8907180");
```

Comment: Hi, what about adding new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }?

Comment: Exactly, you should have var option = new FeedOptions 
{ EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }; IQueryable<SearchInput> queryable =
client.CreateDocumentQuery<SearchInput>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DocumentDBName, DocumentDBCollectionName), option )
        .Where(x => x.Receiver == "8907180");