# C# - .NET- Cross partition query is required but disabled when I Get

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm building a web API with .net core and the CosmosDb SQL API. My post method works, but when I try to get data from the database I get an error "Cross partition query is required but disabled".

I am using the entity framework core for cosmosdb sql and I found a "solution" using feedoptions to enable Cross partition, but I am not using a query the same way they did in the "solution" I found. So I have no idea where to insert the feedoptions, or if that is even the right solution for me.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170004/net-c-sharp-cross-partition-query-is-required-but-disabled-trouble-on-docum) for the "solution" I found.

Get method in SensorController.cs:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Sensor>> Get()

    {

        var bookmarks = _sensorContext.Sensors.ToList();

        return Ok(bookmarks);

    }
```

SensorContext.cs:

```
    public SensorContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }


    public DbSet<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sensor>();
        var sensors = modelBuilder.Entity<Sensor>().Metadata;
        sensors.CosmosSql().CollectionName = "Sensors";
    }
```

I expected to get a list of all the sensors in my database but I just get the Cross origin error instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're using an old version of the CosmosDB Entity Framework.
Make sure to download the latest NuGet package, which is currently:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos -v 3.0.0-preview.18572.1
```

Afterwards, you may try out following walkthrough:
[Announcing Entity Framework Core 2.2 Preview 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/10/17/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2-preview-3/#cosmos-db-provider)

I managed to create and retrieve documents by executing the steps shown in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

If your `sensors` data is so small that you can return all of it within one HTTP request, your probably don't need a partition key on the collection.

It is currently not possible to specify the partition key when using EntityFramework to access CosmosDB. It looks like they are considering it for Version 3 - [see this Github Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12086)

> 3.0 Preview 3
>
> - [..]
> - API to configure document collection facets (for partition keys, RU, size)
> - Handle partition key in queries
>
> Open issues
>
> - [..]
>
>   - How should we handle queries that require feed options to execute across partitions?